# Trying to send / sending html emails with sendmail but shows sourcecode of email

Tags: php, sendmail, html-email

I am trying to send in PHP an HTML email but it always shows the sourcecode of the email in the email program. But it should render the html email as html and not show the sourcecode as email content.

I send my emails like this:

```
$fd = popen("/var/qmail/bin/sendmail -t","w") or die("Couldn't Open Sendmail"); 
    fputs($fd, "To: ".$to2." \n"); 
    fputs($fd, "From: \"Test <test@test.com>\" \n"); 
    fputs($fd, "Subject: ".$subject." \n"); 
    fputs($fd, "X-Mailer: PHP5 \n"); 
    fputs($fd, "Mime-Version: 1.0 \n");
    fputs($fd, " \n");
    fputs($fd, "--".$mime_boundary."");
    fputs($fd, "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"; boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\" \n");
    fputs($fd, "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable \n");   
    fputs($fd, " \n");
    fputs($fd, $sendmail_body." \n"); 
    fputs($fd, "".$mime_boundary."--");
    pclose($fd);
```

The content of the html file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body { font: normal 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It worked now:

> $fd = popen("/var/qmail/bin/sendmail -t","w") or die("Couldn't Open
>   Sendmail");       fputs($fd, "To: ".$to1." \n");          fputs($fd, "From:
>   \"Test \" \n"); 
>         fputs($fd, "Subject: ".$subject." \n");         fputs($fd, "X-Mailer:
>   PHP5 \n");        fputs($fd, "Mime-Version: 1.0 \n");
>         fputs ($fd, "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\" \n");         fputs($fd, " \n");
>         fputs($fd, "--".$mime_boundary."\n");       fputs($fd, "Content-Type:
>   text/html; charset=\"utf-8\" \n");        fputs($fd,
>   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable \n");            fputs($fd, "
>   \n");         fputs($fd, $sendmail_body." \n");       fputs($fd,
>   "--".$mime_boundary."--\n");      pclose($fd);

And the first line of my html file is empty or I add an \n before the html content.

Comment: had to edit my question as i forgot some lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider sending multipart since some clients do not support html mails or just prefer plain text:

```
$headers = "From: Example <example@example.com>\r\n
    MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n
    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary={$mime_boundary}\r\n
    X-Mailer: PHP5";

$message = "This is a MIME-Message. If you can read this your client does not support the MIME format.\r\n
\r\n
{$mime_boundary}\r\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf8;\r\n
\r\n
Text Content encoded in quoted printable
\r\n
\r\n
{$mime_boundary}\r\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf8;\r\n
\r\n
HTML Content encoded in quoted printable
\r\n
--{$mime_boundary}";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

As long as the sendmail path and params are configured correctly in php.ini this will send the mail via sendmail in multipart/alternative type.

Comment: \n or \r\n ? you are confusing me

Comment: \n is the unix-like way, windows uses \r\n and Mac OS just \r - so \r\n will produce a line break on every system... \r\n or \n shouldn't make a difference in mail context, but sometimes they do so...

Comment: its a unix machine / webserver running on linux so i dont neet \r?  sometimes?  so should i definitely use \r\n?

Comment: It depends on the mail server software the recipient uses. But most daemons should be fine just with the \n.

Answer (score 0):

```
fputs($fd, "X-Mailer: PHP5 \n\n");
```

Try removing the second \n because it is a sign of header termination.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<?php
$message=<<<EOL
--frontier
Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
body { font: normal 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
--frontier--
EOL;

$fd = popen("/var/qmail/bin/sendmail -t","w") or die("Couldn't Open Sendmail");

fputs($fd, "To: ".$to." \n");
fputs($fd, "From: \"Example\" <example@example.com> \n");
fputs($fd, "Subject: ".$subject." \n");

fputs($fd,"MIME-Version: 1.0\n");
fputs($fd,"Content-type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"frontier\"\n\n");
fputs($fd,"This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.\n");

fputs($fd, $message);
pclose($fd);
?>
```

I hope it will be helpful

Comment: and my doctype of the html file? should I change all these things now like Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, ...

Comment: tried it (i use a doctype in the html file) but the incoming mail is empty (outlook, not even sourcecode is existing in the email its plain empty) and on iphone it shows the sourcecode